# Proof that the determinant of the Hermitian conjugate of $A$ is the complex conjugate of the determinant of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, unitary-matrices, hermitian-matrices

While revising for an exam, I came across the following proof that the determinant of a unitary matrix $A$ is $\pm 1$:

$$1=\det(I)=\det(A^{\dagger}A) = \det(A)^{*}\det(A)=|\det(A)|^2 $$

This seems to imply that $\det(A^{\dagger})=(\det(A))^*$, but I can't seem to find a proof for this anywhere. Why is this relation the case?

Comment: Transposing doesn't affect the determinant so you only need focus on what happens when you conjugate the matrix. As the determinant is a polynomial function on the entries of $A$, by conjugating the entries you get  the conjugate of the determinant.

Comment: @ラミタ, Thanks for the explanation, not quite sure how I managed to forget the definition of the Hermitian conjugate